# Change HTML table cells value depending on innerText

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, mediawiki

I have the following problem in Google Chrome:

Consider the following table below (I had to remove multiple rows because of the character limitation in stackoverflow, the real table is 2290+ rows)

I want to change the values in the last few columns to either a checkmark or an empty the cell, based on the innerText value of the cell, being either "t" (true) or "f" (false) respectively.

In Firefox, this operation is finished within 1 second, on Chrome it takes literally 5 minutes to complete...

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards,
Hugo Cox

**PS: running the snippet here does not really show the problem because of the limited amount of rows. In reality I have 2290+ rows.**

**EDIT:**
The table gets automatically filled using the following mediawiki code:

```
{{#get_db_data: db=rmdelta |from=c14_cat |order by=labidnr ASC |data=labidnr=labidnr,samplename=samplename,marinecurve2bused=marinecurve2bused,c14age=c14age,c14err=c14err,inuseforchannelage=inuseforchannelage,inuseforgwtinterpol=inuseforgwtinterpol,inuseforldem=inuseforldem,inuseformslrise=inuseformslrise,inuseforvegetationhistory=inuseforvegetationhistory,inuseforlandsubsidence=inuseforlandsubsidence,inuseforcompactquant=inuseforcompactquant}}

{| class="wikitable sortable"
! labIDnr
! Name
! 14C age
! 14C err
! Marine curve
! ChanAge
! GWL
! MSL
! VegHis
! Landsub
! Compaction {{#for_external_table:<nowiki/>
{{!}}-
{{!}} [[RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/{{{labidnr}}}|{{{labidnr}}}]]
{{!}} [[RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/{{{labidnr}}}|{{{samplename}}}]]
{{!}} {{{c14age}}}
{{!}} {{{c14err}}}
{{!}} {{{marinecurve2bused}}}
{{!}} {{{inuseforchannelage}}}
{{!}} {{{inuseforgwtinterpol}}}
{{!}} {{{inuseformslrise}}}
{{!}} {{{inuseforvegetationhistory}}}
{{!}} {{{inuseforlandsubsidence}}}
{{!}} {{{inuseforcompactquant}}}
}}
|}

{{#clear_external_data:}}
<!-- {{Special:PrefixIndex/{{FULLPAGENAME}}/ |1=|columns=3|hideredirects=1|stripprefix=1}} -->
```

**If anyone knows how to paginate such tables in MediaWiki, that could also be a solution to my problem**

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

for (i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  for (j = 4; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
    if (table.rows[i].cells[j].innerText == "t") {
      table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = "&#10004;";
    } else if (table.rows[i].cells[j].innerText == "f") {
      table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = "";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">labIDnr
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Name
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">14C age
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">14C err
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Marine curve
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">ChanAge
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">GWL
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">MSL
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">VegHis
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Landsub
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Compaction
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253">AA-37253</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253">Eigenblok</a>
      </td>
      <td>3100
      </td>
      <td>40
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254">AA-37254</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254">Eigenblok</a>
      </td>
      <td>3475
      </td>
      <td>45
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500">AA-37500</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500">Meteren</a>
      </td>
      <td>3830
      </td>
      <td>40
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521">AA-37521</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521">Meteren</a>
      </td>
      <td>1865
      </td>
      <td>35
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522">AA-37522</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522">Meteren</a>
      </td>
      <td>2900
      </td>
      <td>40
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523">AA-37523</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523">Meteren</a>
      </td>
      <td>4600
      </td>
      <td>45
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583">beta-247583</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583">Kop van Beer M1</a>
      </td>
      <td>8310
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584">beta-247584</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584">Kop van Beer M2</a>
      </td>
      <td>8460
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247585" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247585">beta-247585</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247585" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247585">Kop van Beer M3</a>
      </td>
      <td>8350
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GiF-01614" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GiF-01614">GiF-01614</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GiF-01614" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GiF-01614">no name</a>
      </td>
      <td>8250
      </td>
      <td>300
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-00882" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-00882">GrA-00882</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-00882" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-00882">Monster Polder Westmade</a>
      </td>
      <td>2360
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02544" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02544">GrA-02544</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02544" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02544">Waal VP.4-7</a>
      </td>
      <td>6480
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02717" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02717">GrA-02717</a>
      </td>
      <td>[[RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02717|]]
      </td>
      <td>9540
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04181" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04181">GrA-04181</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04181" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04181">Barendrecht 4</a>
      </td>
      <td>5000
      </td>
      <td>80
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04182" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04182">GrA-04182</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04182" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04182">Barendrecht 7</a>
      </td>
      <td>5430
      </td>
      <td>90
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04183" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04183">GrA-04183</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04183" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04183">Barendrecht 10</a>
      </td>
      <td>5810
      </td>
      <td>90
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04184" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04184">GrA-04184</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04184" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04184">Vlaardingen 20A</a>
      </td>
      <td>4830
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04185" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04185">GrA-04185</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04185" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04185">Vlaardingen 26A</a>
      </td>
      <td>5220
      </td>
      <td>130
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04186" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04186">GrA-04186</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04186" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04186">Vlaardingen 27A</a>
      </td>
      <td>5780
      </td>
      <td>170
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04189" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04189">GrA-04189</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04189" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04189">Vlaardingen 28A</a>
      </td>
      <td>5900
      </td>
      <td>70
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04308" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04308">GrA-04308</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04308" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04308">Barendrecht 1</a>
      </td>
      <td>4470
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04315" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04315">GrA-04315</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04315" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04315">Barendrecht 23</a>
      </td>
      <td>1290
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05205" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05205">GrA-05205</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05205" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05205">Vlaardingen 24A</a>
      </td>
      <td>5430
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05207" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05207">GrA-05207</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05207" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05207">Barendrecht 13</a>
      </td>
      <td>5930
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05208" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05208">GrA-05208</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05208" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05208">Barendrecht 22</a>
      </td>
      <td>6660
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05210" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05210">GrA-05210</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05210" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05210">Vlaardingen 30A</a>
      </td>
      <td>5880
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05211" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05211">GrA-05211</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05211" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05211">Vlaardingen 19A</a>
      </td>
      <td>4780
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05212" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05212">GrA-05212</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05212" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05212">Vlaardingen 21A</a>
      </td>
      <td>5040
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05214" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05214">GrA-05214</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05214" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05214">Vlaardingen 27B</a>
      </td>
      <td>5490
      </td>
      <td>80
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05215" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05215">GrA-05215</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05215" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05215">Barendrecht 19</a>
      </td>
      <td>6360
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05237" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05237">GrA-05237</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05237" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05237">Barendrecht 16</a>
      </td>
      <td>6200
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05326" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05326">GrA-05326</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05326" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05326">Barendrecht 27</a>
      </td>
      <td>5550
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06511" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06511">GrA-06511</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06511" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06511">Oud Alblas 3</a>
      </td>
      <td>5300
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06512" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06512">GrA-06512</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06512" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06512">Oud Alblas 5</a>
      </td>
      <td>5920
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06513" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06513">GrA-06513</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06513" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06513">Oud Alblas 8</a>
      </td>
      <td>6280
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06514" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06514">GrA-06514</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06514" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06514">Oud Alblas 6</a>
      </td>
      <td>6090
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06848" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06848">GrA-06848</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06848" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06848">Bleskensgraaf B</a>
      </td>
      <td>1010
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-07113" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-07113">GrA-07113</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-07113" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-07113">Oud Alblas 4</a>
      </td>
      <td>5770
      </td>
      <td>70
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables#Attributes_on_cells

Comment: Yes, but those attributes cannot be changed depending on the data retrieved.

Comment: What if your program adds `| f | class="f"` ?

Comment: Couldn't you add custom CSS to the page with the table? If so, you can create a custom web font where the letter "t" will be rendered as a check mark and the letter "f" as an empty character, and your table will be presented as expected without any DOM modification:)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe replacing the fragments in the whole table code in one operation would be faster than modifying cells one by one?

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

table.innerHTML = table.innerHTML.replace(/<td>t/g, '<td>&#10004;').replace(/<td>f/g, '<td>');
```

```html
<table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">labIDnr
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Name
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">14C age
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">14C err
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Marine curve
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">ChanAge
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">GWL
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">MSL
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">VegHis
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Landsub
      </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Compaction
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253">AA-37253</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253">Eigenblok</a>
      </td>
      <td>3100
      </td>
      <td>40
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254">AA-37254</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254">Eigenblok</a>
      </td>
      <td>3475
      </td>
      <td>45
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500">AA-37500</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500">Meteren</a>
      </td>
      <td>3830
      </td>
      <td>40
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521">AA-37521</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521">Meteren</a>
      </td>
      <td>1865
      </td>
      <td>35
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522">AA-37522</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522">Meteren</a>
      </td>
      <td>2900
      </td>
      <td>40
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523">AA-37523</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523">Meteren</a>
      </td>
      <td>4600
      </td>
      <td>45
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583">beta-247583</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583">Kop van Beer M1</a>
      </td>
      <td>8310
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584">beta-247584</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584">Kop van Beer M2</a>
      </td>
      <td>8460
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247585" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247585">beta-247585</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247585" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247585">Kop van Beer M3</a>
      </td>
      <td>8350
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GiF-01614" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GiF-01614">GiF-01614</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GiF-01614" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GiF-01614">no name</a>
      </td>
      <td>8250
      </td>
      <td>300
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-00882" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-00882">GrA-00882</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-00882" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-00882">Monster Polder Westmade</a>
      </td>
      <td>2360
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02544" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02544">GrA-02544</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02544" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02544">Waal VP.4-7</a>
      </td>
      <td>6480
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02717" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02717">GrA-02717</a>
      </td>
      <td>[[RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02717|]]
      </td>
      <td>9540
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04181" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04181">GrA-04181</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04181" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04181">Barendrecht 4</a>
      </td>
      <td>5000
      </td>
      <td>80
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04182" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04182">GrA-04182</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04182" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04182">Barendrecht 7</a>
      </td>
      <td>5430
      </td>
      <td>90
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04183" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04183">GrA-04183</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04183" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04183">Barendrecht 10</a>
      </td>
      <td>5810
      </td>
      <td>90
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04184" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04184">GrA-04184</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04184" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04184">Vlaardingen 20A</a>
      </td>
      <td>4830
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04185" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04185">GrA-04185</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04185" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04185">Vlaardingen 26A</a>
      </td>
      <td>5220
      </td>
      <td>130
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04186" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04186">GrA-04186</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04186" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04186">Vlaardingen 27A</a>
      </td>
      <td>5780
      </td>
      <td>170
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04189" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04189">GrA-04189</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04189" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04189">Vlaardingen 28A</a>
      </td>
      <td>5900
      </td>
      <td>70
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04308" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04308">GrA-04308</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04308" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04308">Barendrecht 1</a>
      </td>
      <td>4470
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04315" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04315">GrA-04315</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04315" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04315">Barendrecht 23</a>
      </td>
      <td>1290
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05205" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05205">GrA-05205</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05205" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05205">Vlaardingen 24A</a>
      </td>
      <td>5430
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05207" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05207">GrA-05207</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05207" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05207">Barendrecht 13</a>
      </td>
      <td>5930
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05208" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05208">GrA-05208</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05208" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05208">Barendrecht 22</a>
      </td>
      <td>6660
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05210" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05210">GrA-05210</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05210" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05210">Vlaardingen 30A</a>
      </td>
      <td>5880
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05211" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05211">GrA-05211</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05211" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05211">Vlaardingen 19A</a>
      </td>
      <td>4780
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05212" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05212">GrA-05212</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05212" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05212">Vlaardingen 21A</a>
      </td>
      <td>5040
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05214" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05214">GrA-05214</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05214" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05214">Vlaardingen 27B</a>
      </td>
      <td>5490
      </td>
      <td>80
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05215" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05215">GrA-05215</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05215" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05215">Barendrecht 19</a>
      </td>
      <td>6360
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05237" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05237">GrA-05237</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05237" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05237">Barendrecht 16</a>
      </td>
      <td>6200
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05326" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05326">GrA-05326</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05326" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05326">Barendrecht 27</a>
      </td>
      <td>5550
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06511" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06511">GrA-06511</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06511" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06511">Oud Alblas 3</a>
      </td>
      <td>5300
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06512" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06512">GrA-06512</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06512" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06512">Oud Alblas 5</a>
      </td>
      <td>5920
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06513" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06513">GrA-06513</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06513" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06513">Oud Alblas 8</a>
      </td>
      <td>6280
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06514" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06514">GrA-06514</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06514" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06514">Oud Alblas 6</a>
      </td>
      <td>6090
      </td>
      <td>60
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06848" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06848">GrA-06848</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06848" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06848">Bleskensgraaf B</a>
      </td>
      <td>1010
      </td>
      <td>50
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-07113" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-07113">GrA-07113</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-07113" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-07113">Oud Alblas 4</a>
      </td>
      <td>5770
      </td>
      <td>70
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>t
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
      <td>f
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: It does work in Chrome also, replacing all the corresponding true/false letters. However, I lose the sorting ability... :(.

Comment: Couldn't you call this code before initializing the TableSorter plugin?

Comment: No sorry, not possible. The only way to add custom js in mediawiki is to add it to the common.js file, which get called after the tablesort plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is fast enough?

```js
document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(td => {
  const text = td.innerText;
  if (["t","f"].indexOf(text) !=-1) {
      td.innerHTML = {"t":"&#10004;","f":""}[text]
  }
})
```

```html
<table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">labIDnr </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Name </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">14C age </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">14C err </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Marine curve </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">ChanAge </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">GWL </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">MSL </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">VegHis </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Landsub </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Compaction </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253">AA-37253</a> </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253">Eigenblok</a> </td>
      <td>3100 </td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254">AA-37254</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254">Eigenblok</a></td>
      <td>3475</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500">AA-37500</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500">Meteren</a></td>
      <td>3830</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521">AA-37521</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521">Meteren</a></td>
      <td>1865</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522">AA-37522</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522">Meteren</a></td>
      <td>2900</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523">AA-37523</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523">Meteren</a></td>
      <td>4600</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583">beta-247583</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583">Kop van Beer M1</a></td>
      <td>8310</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584">beta-247584</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584">Kop van Beer M2</a></td>
      <td>8460</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247585" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247585">beta-247585</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247585" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247585">Kop van Beer M3</a></td>
      <td>8350</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GiF-01614" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GiF-01614">GiF-01614</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GiF-01614" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GiF-01614">no name</a></td>
      <td>8250</td>
      <td>300</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-00882" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-00882">GrA-00882</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-00882" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-00882">Monster Polder Westmade</a></td>
      <td>2360</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02544" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02544">GrA-02544</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02544" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02544">Waal VP.4-7</a></td>
      <td>6480</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02717" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02717">GrA-02717</a></td>
      <td>[[RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-02717|]]</td>
      <td>9540</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04181" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04181">GrA-04181</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04181" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04181">Barendrecht 4</a></td>
      <td>5000</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04182" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04182">GrA-04182</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04182" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04182">Barendrecht 7</a></td>
      <td>5430</td>
      <td>90</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04183" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04183">GrA-04183</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04183" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04183">Barendrecht 10</a></td>
      <td>5810</td>
      <td>90</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04184" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04184">GrA-04184</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04184" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04184">Vlaardingen 20A</a></td>
      <td>4830</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04185" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04185">GrA-04185</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04185" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04185">Vlaardingen 26A</a></td>
      <td>5220</td>
      <td>130</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04186" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04186">GrA-04186</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04186" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04186">Vlaardingen 27A</a></td>
      <td>5780</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04189" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04189">GrA-04189</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04189" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04189">Vlaardingen 28A</a></td>
      <td>5900</td>
      <td>70</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04308" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04308">GrA-04308</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04308" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04308">Barendrecht 1</a></td>
      <td>4470</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04315" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04315">GrA-04315</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04315" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-04315">Barendrecht 23</a></td>
      <td>1290</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05205" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05205">GrA-05205</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05205" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05205">Vlaardingen 24A</a></td>
      <td>5430</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05207" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05207">GrA-05207</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05207" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05207">Barendrecht 13</a></td>
      <td>5930</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05208" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05208">GrA-05208</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05208" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05208">Barendrecht 22</a></td>
      <td>6660</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05210" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05210">GrA-05210</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05210" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05210">Vlaardingen 30A</a></td>
      <td>5880</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05211" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05211">GrA-05211</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05211" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05211">Vlaardingen 19A</a></td>
      <td>4780</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05212" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05212">GrA-05212</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05212" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05212">Vlaardingen 21A</a></td>
      <td>5040</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05214" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05214">GrA-05214</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05214" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05214">Vlaardingen 27B</a></td>
      <td>5490</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05215" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05215">GrA-05215</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05215" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05215">Barendrecht 19</a></td>
      <td>6360</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05237" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05237">GrA-05237</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05237" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05237">Barendrecht 16</a></td>
      <td>6200</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05326" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05326">GrA-05326</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05326" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-05326">Barendrecht 27</a></td>
      <td>5550</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06511" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06511">GrA-06511</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06511" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06511">Oud Alblas 3</a></td>
      <td>5300</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06512" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06512">GrA-06512</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06512" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06512">Oud Alblas 5</a></td>
      <td>5920</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06513" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06513">GrA-06513</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06513" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06513">Oud Alblas 8</a></td>
      <td>6280</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06514" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06514">GrA-06514</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06514" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06514">Oud Alblas 6</a></td>
      <td>6090</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06848" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06848">GrA-06848</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06848" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-06848">Bleskensgraaf B</a></td>
      <td>1010</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-07113" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-07113">GrA-07113</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-07113" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/GrA-07113">Oud Alblas 4</a></td>
      <td>5770</td>
      <td>70</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Using a class and CSS

```css
.f { background-color:red}
.t::after { content: "✔️"}
```

```html
<table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">labIDnr </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Name </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">14C age </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">14C err </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Marine curve </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">ChanAge </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">GWL </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">MSL </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">VegHis </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Landsub </th>
      <th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Compaction </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253">AA-37253</a> </td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37253">Eigenblok</a> </td>
      <td>3100 </td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254">AA-37254</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37254">Eigenblok</a></td>
      <td>3475</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500">AA-37500</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37500">Meteren</a></td>
      <td>3830</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521">AA-37521</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37521">Meteren</a></td>
      <td>1865</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522">AA-37522</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37522">Meteren</a></td>
      <td>2900</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523">AA-37523</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/AA-37523">Meteren</a></td>
      <td>4600</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583">beta-247583</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247583">Kop van Beer M1</a></td>
      <td>8310</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="t"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584">beta-247584</a></td>
      <td><a href="/wiki/RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584" title="RijnMaasDelta:C14Catalogue/beta-247584">Kop van Beer M2</a></td>
      <td>8460</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="t"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
      <td class="f"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Sadly no.. On Chrome I still receive a blank page for several minutes untill all the rows are completed. I am generating a table on mediawiki using their parser. I fill the table with the data from my database connection. However, for some reason mediawiki does not include a function to populate the table using pagination.

Comment: Can you change the cell content to be a data-attribute or a class?

Comment: See second example

Comment: Sorry, I thought I could but alas. This MediaWiki is very limiting, I updated my question to show how exactly the table is being constructed.